# How to add Named Ranges to sub-paragraph elements in Google apps-script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, named-ranges

I would like to implement a 'html-span-like' feature inside Google Documents but whenever I try to add a `NamedRange` to a substring of text inside a Google Document, the range is merged with previous text in the same paragraph.

In result, the `NamedRange` is applied to the whole paragraph.

Here's my test case :

```js
function createTextNamedRange(){
  // Retrieve the current document's body
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var docBody = doc.getBody();

  // Add a new paragraph with text {NotNamed}
  var para = docBody.appendParagraph('{NotNamed}');

  // Append some text that will be named ( .appendText() method returns a Text element )
  var textElem = para.appendText('{NamedText}');

  // Build a range for the Text element
  var range=doc.newRange().addElement(textElem).build();
  // Name the range and append it to the document
  doc.addNamedRange('myNamedRange',range);
}
```

I then display the content of the `NamedRange` using the `Logger` class in this function:

```js
function getTextNamedRange(){
  // Retrieve the named range
  var namedRanges =    DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getNamedRanges();

  // Iterate through each instance of name 'myNamedRange' (there's only one)
  for (var nr in namedRanges){
    var namedRange = namedRanges[nr];

    // A range may contain several RangeElements, iterate through them
    var rangeElements = namedRange.getRange().getRangeElements();
    for(var re in rangeElements) {

      // Get the text of each RangeElement and display it in the logger
      var text = rangeElements[re].getElement().asText().getText();
      Logger.log('Text with namedRange (' + namedRange.getName() + ') : "' + text +'"');
    }
  }
}
```

I would assume to get `{NamedText}` as an output but the Log Window tells this:

```
Text with namedRange (myNamedRange) : "{NotNamed}{NamedText}"
```

As it can be seen, the range was applied to the unmarked as well as the named text.

I found [a workaround detailed below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30664391/940745) but it's definitely not to my taste: it consists of adding empty inline images between the `.appendText()` calls. This way the Text elements are not merged.

I'm still looking for a better solution.

Answer (score 5):

The following is for **WORKAROUND ONLY** but appears to work.

It relies on `InlineImage` insertion before and after the `Text` chunk that has to be Named.

This prevent the `NamedRange` to merge when applied to chunk of `Text` inside a `Paragraph`

```js
function createTextNamedRangeWorkaround(){
  // WORKAROUND: prevent the Text Merging (and hence the NamedRange merging)
  // by separating Text Elements with blank Inline Images

  // Import a blank PNG file
  // NOTE: This shouldn't be fetched each time 
  //       but only once and passed as an argument
  var blankImage = UrlFetchApp.fetch('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d2/Blank.png');

  // Retrieve the current document's body
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var docBody = doc.getBody();

  // Add a new paragraph with text {NotNamed}
  var para = docBody.appendParagraph('{NotNamed}');

  // WORKAROUND HERE : 
  para.appendInlineImage(blankImage.getBlob());
  // Append some text
  var textElem1 = para.appendText('{NamedText1}');

  // WORKAROUND HERE : 
  para.appendInlineImage(blankImage.getBlob());
  // Append some text
  var textElem2 = para.appendText('{NamedText2}');

  // Build Named ranges after text insertion (see notice below)
  var range1=doc.newRange().addElement(textElem1).build();
  // Name the range and append it to the document
  doc.addNamedRange('Range1',range1);
  var range2=doc.newRange().addElement(textElem2).build();
  // Name the range and append it to the document
  doc.addNamedRange('Range2',range2);
}
```

After execution the document is appended with a new paragraph containing three words separated by two blank inline PNGs

```
{NotNamed}{NamedText1}{NamedText2}
```

And the execution of my `getTextNamedRange()` shows the desired behaviour:

```
Text with namedRange (Range1) : "{NamedText1}"
Text with namedRange (Range2) : "{NamedText2}"
```

**Important notices:**

- Named ranges must be applied alltogether after the last `Text` insertion, otherwise, previous NamedRanges adopt new insertions and appendings.
- `InlineImages` can't be removed from parent `Paragraph` using `image.removeFromParent()` because this causes the `Text` elements (and the `NamedRange`) to be merged again

Comment: It is mind blowing that this is still the only way to get inter paragraph named ranges to work as they **should**. For any other poor souls stuck trying to get this to work, you can also use the cursor functions instead of paragraphs. `cursor.insertInlineImage(blob)` -> `cursor.insertText("your text")` -> `cursor.insertInlineImage(blob)`. Thank you so much for writing this up, this is still undocumented and we were stuck for hours coming up with a solution until we found this.